# Eliminar texto entre parentesis, y los parentesis en BBEdit

Tags: regex, replace

¿Cuál es la formula para elminar los paréntesis y el texto dentro de los parentesis con BBEdit?

Ejemplo:

> En realidad, solo una". (Teléfono) Sí. "¿Mamá?".

Querria eliminar `(Teléfono)`

Comment: Hola! Si agregas lo que has intentado hasta el momento los usuarios te podrán ayudar mejor y asi tu pregunta queda mejor

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `[(][^)]*[)]`

Explicación:

```
[(]    # Paréntesis izquierdo (se tiene que "escapar" puesto
       # que se usa para los grupos de captura)
       # Otra manera de escaparlo podría haber sido: \(
[^)]*  # Cualquier cosa que no sea paréntesis derecho, 0 o más veces
[)]    # Paréntesis derecho (escapado)
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/u5JEN4/1)